# http.server "code 404, message File not found"

Tags: python, python-module, http.server

I'm hosting a Python http server from a simple HTML folder on my laptop using `py -m http.server`. It works fine on the browser end, (tested from computers on my LAN) but the output often says
`::ffff:192.168.1.212 - - [19/Dec/2021 21:58:38] code 404, message File not found`
what's with that? (obviously the date/time and local IP are often different, just pasting full line for clarification)

Comment: The browser is requesting a file that does not exist in your source directory. Most likely the favicon. Unlikely but If you don't know HTTP status codes you might want to read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: @SujalSingh it has a favicon i  was wondering what file its missing. when it was missing favicon it said so, didn't say missing message file

Comment: you could open up dev tools in your browser and check which request is getting a 404 response in the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the error message you given, there should be another one indicating which file the browser is requesting:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
::1 - - [20/Dec/2021 00:59:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [20/Dec/2021 00:59:02] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [20/Dec/2021 00:59:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

In the above example the browser is requesting `/favicon.ico`, which is not found.